# Websocket Server Architecture

Tags: websocket

Need some advice on architecture. I've built a chess site, and want to add multiplayer capabilities. I recently asked a question here on what does the path at the end of the url do as in:

```
"ws://<%= Request.Url.Host %>:<%= WebSocketPort %>/sample"
```

I understand it now. So, if I needed the capability to only send messages from the server to all logged in users, then I need something to handles games between users, and then one for chatting maybe, would I have something like the following?

```
var ss = new WebSocket('ws://<%= Request.Url.Host %>:<%= SecureWebSocketPort %>/server');

var gs = new WebSocket('ws://<%= Request.Url.Host %>:<%= SecureWebSocketPort %>/games');

var cs = new WebSocket('ws://<%= Request.Url.Host %>:<%= SecureWebSocketPort %>/chat');
```

Then on these three, I could set up my events accordingly. This seems like it would work, however, it doesn't seem like the right way to go. I suppose the message I send back could have info on how to separate things but it would be overloaded I think.

Any thoughts on how I might want to separate the functionality as described above?

Comment: If you are looking for a self hosted .NET solution then the following may be of interest: * [XSockets](http://xsockets.net)
* [SuperWebSockets](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is really different channels and message types for the same overall application. I think a more appropriate (and efficient) solution would be to establish a single WebSocket connection to a single URL and then define your own messages and session management.

If [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) is an option for you, there are lots of examples and recipes for this type of thing. Search on google for "Socket.IO chat", "Socket.IO session", "Socket.IO authorization", etc. The [Socket.IO wiki](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki/) is probably a really good place to start.

Even if you don't use Socket.IO, you still probably want a single connection with your own messages and session management. For this sort of thing, using JSON messages is probably the way to go (since bandwidth for chess/chat is not going to be an issue). Most languages have really easy JSON serialization/deserialization to native data types.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks much for your help. I was also thinking along the lines of having the message handle the different functionality in the form of JSON so we were thinking the same there. Now, for the session management, I'll have to check out this Socket.IO. When you say "channels" is that session management then in this context? Thanks much.

Comment: @David Whitten, channels would really be something you would define in the context of your application. I.e. an in IRC sense the channel is the channels/rooms you are connected to. In a chess server, the channels would probably be the game(s) you are participating in. There are Socket.IO examples of session management and authentication and you're application server would map session/user to channels.

Comment: Yes, after a bit of struggling I've figured out what I needed to do. It's amazing what one can do with a little bit of javascript.

Comment: @David Whitten, don't forget to select an answer if you feel one of them is the right one for your question otherwise people searching for the same problem often pass over the question in a list if it has no selected answer.